# DLL cannot be found when I specify the path and the dll has no missing dependencies

Tags: dll, vb6, file-not-found, depends

I am writing a program which refers to a dll using the words "Declare"

Whenever I run the program I get an error saying "File not found: x.dll". I tried specifying the whole path, still an error. I tried registering the dll, gives me an error.

I opened the Visual Studio Depends program to see if the dll has missing dependencies and found nothing that could be troubling it.

What could be the cause of this?

Thanks!

Comment: `Declare` means its not a COM dll and so does not require registration.  I would run procmon from sysinternals and look at what the exe is trying to load, looking at the paths/results.

Comment: I am running procmon now and I found that the same dll I need is being used by many, MANY, programs. Is there a way I can pipeline it somehow with another program?

Comment: I wouldn't do that. You probably aren't specifying the pathname correctly.  Sorry if I'm sounding simplistic, but there's no other reason that I can think of that you can't access the DLL if other programs are doing so successfully.

Comment: The path name is in Program Files, I don't know if that's why it gives me an error.